Replicate complex space diagrams in tikz
I want to replicate the following diagrams in tikz.  I want to make the red thick arrows.  Do I draw the arrow with \addplot3 inside axis ?
I do get the problem
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}).

Here is the implementation
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    view={60}{30}, % Set the viewing angle
    axis lines=center,
    xlabel={$omega$},
    ylabel={$\Re$},
    zlabel={$\Im$},
    xmin=-5, xmax=5,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    zmin=-1, zmax=1,
    enlargelimits=true,
    grid=major,
    ticks=none
  ]

    %% Add arrows for the axes
    \addplot3[domain=-2:2, samples=2, thick] coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,0,0)};
    \addplot3[domain=-1:1, samples=2, thick] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,1,0)};
    \addplot3[domain=-1:1, samples=2, thick] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0,5)};
  
    \addplot3 [red,thick,stealth] coordinates {(3,0,0) (3,0.5,0)};
  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Here is the task to produce


Welcome! What do you have so far? What have you tried? Can you provide the code you've got and explain the specific problem you're having? General strategy: find a similar post or an example in the manual, copy, modify, repeat. I assume you have some familiarity with tikz/pgf or you wouldn't be asking to use that specifically. If not but you are (for some reason) determined on tikz, start with the tutorials at the beginning of the manual and learn to draw something simpler (2D) first.

Welcome. // Unfortunately it seems to be a common mis-take, that one of the axis-environments somehow draws vectors. They are not meant for that: they are used to plot xy or xyz DATA ...

How would I draw a general red arrow exactly in some specified direction ?

Good qeustion. See my answer: you use polar notation and relative coordinates. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720557/245790

Here is one way to do it with plain Tikz, demonstrating basic design elements. I suggest to consult the pgfmanual in parallel, especially its nice tutorials.

(1) So basically you do a 2D-drawing. Its basic element used over and over again here is:
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,.5);

which draws a line between both coordinates (by chance: through origin) and puts an arrow-tip at the end. But for this purpose it's better to use polar-notation of the coordinates, like:
\draw[->] (30:1) -- (-30:2);

and this time its a line (visual vector) off-origin.

(2) Next you need a basic understanding of the path concept in Tikz. Syntactically:

a path starts with \
ends with ;
and performs actions (commands) in between, like draw (watch the missing \)

So this way you'd draw AND put an extra node (with some text) at the first coordinate:
\draw[->] (0,0) node {some text} -- (1,.5);

while this way you'd put it at the second coordinate:
\draw[->] (30:1) -- (-30:2) node {other text};


(3) Now let's have a closer look at my solution. The most important line to draw is this one:
    % ~~~ frequency ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (150:2) -- (-30:2) node[anchor=north]{Frequency}
                                 node[pos=.22,nil](M){}
                                 node[pos=.77,nil](P){}
                                 ;


it's the falling diagonal
which puts a node at its end for text Frequency
and adds two other empty nodes, where all we need are their coordinates, hence the names (M) and (P)
the pos option puts these nodes at relativ positions along the whole path

What's left?
The anchors just specify the reference point for a node, if you don't want the default "center".
You can also specify relative coordinates with a + like here:
    % ~~~ red arrows ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[ra] (M) -- +(20:.8);

Styles are useful, at least as abbreviations. The self-defined nil actually makes these nodes to a point, i.e. prevents drawing a white rectangle over the starting point of your red arrow.


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},
    nil/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt},
    ra/.style={red,line width=1.5pt,->},
 ]
    % ~~~ frequency ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (150:2) -- (-30:2) node[anchor=north]{Frequency}
                                 node[pos=.22,nil](M){}
                                 node[pos=.77,nil](P){}
                                 ;
    
    % ~~~ R ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (200:1) -- (20:2) node[anchor=west]{$\Re$};

    % ~~~ I ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (0,0) node[anchor=north]{$0$} 
                    -- (90:1.5) node[anchor=west]{$\Im$};
    
    % ~~~ red arrows ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[ra] (M) -- +(20:.8);
    
    \draw[ra] (P) node[black,shift=(200:.4)]{$+\omega_c$} 
                  -- +(20:.8) node[black,shift=(20:.2)]{$\frac{1}{2}$} ;
    
    % ~~~ some label ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node at (90:2){$v(t) = \cos(\omega_c t)$}; 
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Would you be so kind to explain the interpretation of things like (20:.8).  And how to determine appropriate values ?

All are estimates. I chose 20deg for the R axis, with 0deg pointing to the right. Radius 0.8cm is another estimate, which seemed to look good enough. „Appropriate“ is what looks right to you: it’s more art than math. transformation, AND which doesn’t obscure the drawing (i.e. leaving enough space where needed).

So if you go with 20deg for R, its opposite direction would be 20+180=200deg. While perpendicular directions would point along 90+20=110deg, and 270+20=290deg = -70deg (or aboves 110+180=290deg)

Then polar coordinates are actually rotations in the plane of the page ?

No, it’s simpler: a different way to express coordinates. E.d. cartesian (1,1) is the same as polar (45:1.414). I suggest to get rid of the rotation idea.


Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true':
document has been generated with the most recent feature set
(\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}).

Is not an error - it is a notification and perfectly normal.
Your error comes from the missing - in your arrow option. You need -stealth (deprecated) or better -Stealth. An arrow tip from the arrows.meta library.
PgfPlots is not just for plotting data. It is a consistent way to make graphs and plots of any kind. You can in a consistent way create 2D and 3D graphs with axis, grid, ticks, labels, legends and more. It is most definitely the correct way to make your graph with vectors.
Instead of doing your vectors with addplot (they are not real plots that needs e.g. legends), you can use draw inside the axis like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={60}{30},
axis lines=center,
ylabel={$\Re$}, zlabel={$\Im$},
xmin=-5, xmax=5,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
zmin=-1, zmax=1,
enlargelimits=true,
ticks=none,
]
\addplot3[draw=red, thick, -Stealth] coordinates {(3,0,0) (3,0.5,0)} node[pos=0, left]{$\omega_c$};
\draw[draw=red, thick, -Stealth] (-3,0,0)node[left]{$-\omega_c$} -- (-3,0.5,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If you choose to do everything manually in pure TikZ instead of TikZ with PGFPlots you can still use 3D(fake 3D, but still coordinates with three numbers), so the command would be the exact same:
\draw[draw=red, thick, -Stealth] (-3,0,0)node[left]{$-\omega_c$} -- (-3,0.5,0);
